# Uploading files to FTPS via proxy

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, ftps

I need to upload files to FTPS via a proxy (to have a static IP which is allowed by FTPS server).

Can I use .NET built-in classes? Maybe a code sample, I didn't find any good sample which would work with proxy. Or do I need a 3rd party component?

Can I use HTTP proxy server, or do I need some special server?

Comment: you can look at a 3rd party component [FTPS better known as FTP over SSL](http://blog-of-darius.blogspot.com/2011/07/ftps-also-known-as-ftp-over-ssl-example.html) keep in mind this is different than `SFTP`

Comment: here is a really good link that you can utilize - http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_security/authentication/article.php/c15051/ASPNET-FTP-with-SSL.htm